# having problems creating jquery + PHP +MySQL chatroom

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I have read several tutorials on chartrooms in jquery and JavaScript with a back-end of PHP and mysql. I know the php part of this will work (or if it won't then I can fix it more than likley) however the problem lies in my extremely limited knowledge of jquery. So hopefully someone here can give some insight on where on where my (probably extremely obvious) error lies I would greatly appreciate it.

Additionally: I am not looking for one person to show me EXACTLY what needs to be done, just a push in the right direction because I couldn't find anything that was actually helpful.

main page:

```
<?php
include 'connect.php';
session_start();

include 'include/notloggedin.php';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="windows-1252">
    <title>zyrnith</title>
    <link href="stylesheets/all.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="stylesheets/game.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
                function scTop(){
     $("#messages").animate({scrollTop:$("#messages")[0].scrollHeight});
    }
    function load_new_stuff(){
     localStorage['lpid']=$(".messagerow:last").attr("title");
     $("#messages").load("include/messages.php",function(){
      if(localStorage['lpid']!=$(".messagerow:last").attr("title")){
       scTop();
      }
     });
    }
    $(document).ready(function(){
     scTop();
     });
    $('#chatbox').keydown(function() {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
      val=$(this).find("#chatbox").val();
      if (val != ""){
       $.post("include/sendchat.php",{message:val},function(){
        load_new_stuff();
       });
      }
      return false;
  })
  });


    $( document ).ready(function()
    {
        setInterval(load_new_stuff(), 1000);
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="everything">
        <div style="width:200px; float: left;">
            test
        </div>
        <div id="chat">
            <div id="messages">
            <?php
                include 'include/messages.php';
            ?>
            </div>
            <form id="chatform">
                <input type="text" id="chatbox" maxlength="150" name="message" />
            </form>
        </div>
        <div style="float: right; text-align: right; width:200px;">
            <?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>
            <br />
            <a style="height: 150px; padding-right: 5px; font-variant: small-caps;" href="logout.php">Logout</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

sendchat.php:

```
<?php
include("connect.php");
if(!isset($_SESSION['userid']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'])=='xmlhttprequest'){
 die("<script>window.location.reload()</script>");
}
if(isset($_SESSION['userid']) && isset($_POST['message']))
{
 $message=htmlspecialchars($_POST['message']);
 if($message){
  mysql_query("INSERT INTO chat (user,message) VALUES ('$_SESSION['userid']','$message')") or die(mysql_error());
 }
}
?>
```

any other info you need let me know and I can update this.

File Structure:

- include

  - messages.php
  - notloggedin.php
  - sendchat.php
- changelog.txt
- connect.php
- error.php
- chat.php
- index.php
- login.php
- logout.php
- register.php

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )  -- Line 33

Comment: what is the problem? what errors are you getting?

Comment: Nothing happens, no errors. Just reloads the page, no new database entry, no errors, nothing.

Comment: Does the javascript console provide any insight?

Comment: Start from [Code Academy](http://www.codecademy.com/en/tracks/jquery).

Comment: Like I stated previously my JavaScript knowledge is basically trial and error, so tell me what I need to do to get you more information and I will but I am not familiar with the JavaScript console

Comment: Learning to code is all about learning to debug. If you don't have any clue what is going wrong, at least try to make the code that is causing the problem as small as possible. So start removing parts and find out what it does, or doesn't. If you don't know what it does, try to find that out before asking to fix a whole application.

Answer (score 0):

If you can share the Javascript console from the browser you are using can show some insights onto what the problem is. If you are new to dev, use the following to show the console:

On chrome and Mac: 
    cmd + option (alt) + I 
will open up the console.  Choose the last option, Console on that window.

Also, in the beginning of the code you have missed, not sure if you missed while you copied the code.

```
<?php
```

On server side, you can check for php related errors.

```
error.log
```

Comment: Using opera (chrome based) while I try to send a message console stays clear.

Comment: Post the server side error. Find "Error.log" file in the same folder as you have the php. Try in Chorme and Firefox as well.

Comment: I don't have access to that part of the server. No error on chrome either.

Comment: Do a right-click on the document and see what "View Source" shows. Post it here.  I really doubt if the server is sending anything back to the client. Also, more details like how the php scripts are organized shall be helpful.

Comment: pasted source from chrome and file structure.

Comment: Ok. All of them are php files and I am certain that it's erroring out at the server side. You should be able to get to "error.log" file. How are you copying these files to the folders on the webserver? That file should be in the same location.  I am pretty sure that you have PHP bug that is not letting anything sent to the browser.

Comment: ftp, i dont have access to the actually php files though just the actual public area of the server.

Comment: it's pretty much closed now. You don't have access to the server and certainly can't debug. Sorry, can't help here much.

Comment: worked out some major problems. Finally found an error, added to original question. hopefully it will provide some insight.

Answer (score 0):

```
   function scTop(){
        $("#messages").animate({scrollTop:$("#messages")[0].scrollHeight});
    }
    function load_new_stuff(){
        localStorage['lpid']=$(".messagerow:last").attr("title");
        $("#messages").load("include/messages.php",function(){
            if(localStorage['lpid']!=$(".messagerow:last").attr("title")){
                scTop();
            }
        });
    }
    $(document).ready(function(){
        scTop();
    });
    $('#chatbox').keydown(function() {
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
            val=$(this).find("#chatbox").val();
            if (val !== ""){
                $.post("include/sendchat.php",{message:val},function(){
                    load_new_stuff();
                });}}});


    $( document ).ready(function()
    {
        setInterval(load_new_stuff(), 1000);
    });
```